# Finding USB device path in Linux

Tags: linux, debian

I am working with a software that needs the path for a device connected to my PC using USB such as `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

How can I find which one is associated with the device I have connected?

Comment: You can able to find the answer in the below link http://askubuntu.com/questions/311772/how-do-i-know-the-device-path-to-an-usb-stick

Comment: My connected device shown as ttyUSB1, but I could't mount it. I got this error: mount: /dev/ttyUSB1 is not a block device

Comment: @Mr.Hyde, /dev/ttyUSB1 is normally a **character device**, not a block device.  It's meaningless to mount a tty!  If you have a block device, it's likely to have a symlink in `/dev/disk/by-id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian's `udev` is configured to write helpful, repeatable symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`.  One of these paths is likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting your USB drive, run (as root):

```
fdisk -l
```

This command will show you all connected drives, including paths and partitions.

Comment: Good answer to a different question.  `fdisk -l` lists partitions, not serial devices.